# Extract values in DisparityImage

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to extract the values of certain points in a stereo_msgs::DisparityImage message. I'm assuming that the values are stored in "sensor_msgs/Image image" inside the DisparityImage message. So I did this:

```
void disparityrelay::callback(const stereo_msgs::DisparityImage::ConstPtr& disparity)
{
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
    try
    {
        cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(disparity->image, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_32FC1);
    }
    catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
    {
        ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
        return;
    }

    imshow("Display", cv_ptr->image);
    cv::waitKey(3);
}
```

But all I got is a black and white image. Did I do something wrong, or am I just not approaching this correctly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58370/extract-values-in-disparityimage/) by [superawesomepandacat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3651/superawesomepandacat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2013-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Float values need to be normalize to 0~1 so that imshow can display it.

---

Originally posted by [superawesomepandacat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3651/superawesomepandacat/) with karma: 172 on 2013-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0